# Moving words in a cell to individual columns

Tags: r, text, text-mining

I have a csv file that has a column with multiple words in each cell. I wonder if there's any R function to move words in each cell to individual cells. 
The following are data in two cells in the dataset:

arecapalm,betelnut,konkan,nature,traveldiaries,mirrorlessframes
passangerstories,chakarmanee,atranginikhil,maharashtra,india

Thanks. Any help appreciated.

Chamil

Comment: Can you give an example of what the output format should be?

Comment: you can use tidyr's `separate`

Comment: So, if  the input is cat dog rat in a single cell, the ideal output would have these words in separate cells in a row.

Comment: I tried         ============hashtags <- as.character(betel$hashtags)
separate(hashtags)=======but it is giving me an error message. Error in UseMethod("separate_") : 
  no applicable method for 'separate_' applied to an object of class "character"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's assume this data.frame:

```
require(dplyr)
require(tidyr)
df<-data.frame(id=1:2, words=c("arecapalm,betelnut,konkan,nature,traveldiaries,mirrorlessframes","passangerstories,chakarmanee,atranginikhil,maharashtra,india"))
df

#  id                                                           words
#1  1 arecapalm,betelnut,konkan,nature,traveldiaries,mirrorlessframes
#2  2    passangerstories,chakarmanee,atranginikhil,maharashtra,india
```

Then we can run this using `dplyr` and `tidyr` to break down the words cells into multiple columns:

```
df %>% separate_rows(words) %>% 
   group_by(id) %>% 
   mutate(wordid=row_number()) %>% 
   spread(wordid,words,sep=".")

# A tibble: 2 x 7
# Groups:   id [2]
     id wordid.1         wordid.2    wordid.3      wordid.4    wordid.5      wordid.6        
  <int> <chr>            <chr>       <chr>         <chr>       <chr>         <chr>           
1     1 arecapalm        betelnut    konkan        nature      traveldiaries mirrorlessframes
2     2 passangerstories chakarmanee atranginikhil maharashtra india         NA
```